# Javascript change image src with fade out and in

Tags: javascript, image, fade

I'm new to JavaScript and i'd like to change automatically `src` of an `<img>` dynamically in a loop of couple images like 4 of them with use of fade in and fade out. This `<img>` tag has CSS class so it will be easy to select it wit JavaScript.

HTML:

`<img class="zawartosc_prawy_mac" src="prawy_1.png">`

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(setTimeout(function () {

                        $(".zawartosc_prawy_mac").each(function (i, e) {
                            $(this).attr("src", "prawy_2.png");
                        })
                    },5000));
```

I managed to make it switch (thanks to Vladimir Drenovski) and to add a delay to this switch but i have no idea how to make it in to the loop and how to ease it in and out.

Comment: Sounds like you want someone to do all the coding for you.

Comment: Like i said im new to javascript, i don't want all the code, i'd like someone to show me how to do it

Comment: If i would like all coding to be done for me i would use a plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use Jquery to achieve that using the following code:

```
$(".images-to-change-class").each(function(i, e){
     $(this).attr("src","image-location");
})
```

`.images-to-change-class` represents the class name of multiple elements holding images.
`image-location represents` the value you need to change src to.

Comment: Will try to use it, i'll tell how it worked for me and if i understood it properly :)

Comment: feel free to ask further questions, making a JSFiddle is good thing to do so i can help you out further

Comment: Where do i add delay to this code ?? and should i use it every time for every change of picture ??

Comment: The code works only when you are trying to change multiple images at the same time, you can always call setTimeout() inside the each() method. If your task is is to change multiple pictures at the same time - yes, otherwise - no. Everything depends on what you are trying to accomplish with this.